# How see pending push on git?

Tags: git, git-push

How can I see my pending push using line command after to do several git commit?

I have tried git status but this one only shows information about pending commit or untracked files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on, say, `master`, do `git log origin/master..master`. This will show you all the commits that are on your local `master` but not on the server.